# What's the replacement of clipTo after fabricjs v2?

Tags: fabricjs

The **clipTo** function is deprecated since 2.0, is there any replacement for it or this feature is just removed?

Answer (score 0):

They still working on it (Clipping API)

https://github.com/fabricjs/fabricjs.com/issues/193

https://github.com/fabricjs/api-discussion/issues/1

Still work in progress